# Build image using terraform, and deploying to AWS ECR via CircleCI

Tags: docker, terraform, dockerfile, circleci

I have done everything, except deploying through CircleCI. when I run terraform apply, I can use the image within ECR, then my terraform is creating a cluster, task definition and a service. Everything is going fine; however, when CircleCI tries to run the docker commands it failed.

I'm just giving up after the whole day stuck here.

This is part of the code I think is compromise:

````
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "2.24.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "docker" {
  registry_auth {
    address  = data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.proxy_endpoint
    username = data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.user_name
    password = data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.password
  }
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "this" {
  name                 = "${var.service_name}-vpn"
  image_tag_mutability = "MUTABLE"

  image_scanning_configuration {
    scan_on_push = true
  }

  encryption_configuration {
    encryption_type = "AES256"
  }
}

resource "docker_registry_image" "this" {
  name = "${aws_ecr_repository.this.repository_url}:latest"

  build {
    context    = "./${var.service_name}-vpn"
    dockerfile = "Dockerfile"
  }
}```

**This is the output from CircleCI which doesn't happen on my computer; I have tried though, using the dind image. I still get the same error.**


> Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Initializing provider plugins...
- Reusing previous version of kreuzwerker/docker from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/aws from the dependency lock file
- Installing kreuzwerker/docker v2.24.0...
- Installed kreuzwerker/docker v2.24.0 (self-signed, key ID BD080C4571C6104C)
- Installing hashicorp/aws v4.18.0...
- Installed hashicorp/aws v4.18.0 (signed by HashiCorp)

Partner and community providers are signed by their developers.
If you'd like to know more about provider signing, you can read about it here:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/plugins/signing.html

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
/root/connections-terraform
connections-terraform
data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token: Reading...
data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.this: Reading...
data.aws_iam_role.vpn_task: Reading...
data.aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role: Reading...
data.aws_ecs_cluster.this: Reading...
data.aws_iam_role.vpn_task: Read complete after 0s [id=vpnTask]
data.aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role: Read complete after 0s [id=ecsTaskExecutionRole]
data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token: Read complete after 0s [id=*********]
data.aws_ecs_cluster.this: Read complete after 0s [id=arn:aws:ecs:*********:************:cluster/***-***]
2023-01-10T04:50:39.213Z [*****] provider.terraform-provider-docker_v2.24.0: Response contains error diagnostic: tf_provider_addr=provider tf_rpc=Configure @module=sdk.proto diagnostic_detail= diagnostic_severity=***** tf_proto_version=5.3 @caller=github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.14.1/tfprotov5/internal/diag/diagnostics.go:55 diagnostic_summary="Error pinging Docker server: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?" tf_req_id=******bc-d33d-*****-347d-****a137c68d timestamp=2023-01-10T04:50:39.213Z
2023-01-10T04:50:39.213Z [*****] vertex "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker\"]" error: Error pinging Docker server: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.this: Read complete after 0s [id=arn:aws:secretsmanager:*********:************:secret:sandbox/vpn-832Y9J]
╷
│ Error: Error pinging Docker server: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker"],
│   on main.tf line 16, in provider "docker":
│   16: provider "docker" {
│ 
╵
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
ERRO[0005] 1 error occurred:
    * exit status 1

**This is part of my .circleci/confi.yml file **

version: 2.1

defaults: &defaults
  docker:
    - image: docker:20.10.22-dind
      aws_auth:
````

Comment: You don't need to use the kreuzwerker provider, you can just use docker commands: https://circleci.com/docs/building-docker-images/. Additionally, there are also CircleCI orbs: https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/aws-ecr.

Comment: @MarkoE So basically, I removed docker as a provider, and the docker_registry_image. Instead, within the config.yml: `docker_version: &docker_version | orbs: aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@8.2.1 aws-ecs: circleci/aws-ecs@3.2.0 | setup_remote_docker: | aws-ecr/build-and-push-image | aws-ecs/deploy-service-update`

Comment: Ok, so you're telling me it worked? :)

Comment: @MarkoE I could pass to the next stage within circleci, but I am having a hard time with issue now where my Dockerfile has `COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh ` ; however, I am getting this error message > `/entrypoint.sh not found: not found`. I have found that I need to copy somehow the file(s) to the remote_docker. Any hints?

Comment: Do you have an entrypoint script at all in your code? If not, you can remove it from the Dockerfile. If yes, you need to create it in your repository.

Comment: @MarkoE yes, I do have one. creating the image with copying the files work fine when I create the image and push it ecr from my host. The problem is creating the image from CircleCI; that's where COPY thrown an error. How can I a create the script in my repo?

Comment: @MarkoE I just posted the final code. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the code on my question works fine, it didn't via CircleCI. So, the way I solved this was as follows:

I removed from my main.tf the docker provider and the docker_registry_image, and I just kept the aws_ecr_repository.

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "this" {                                
  name = "${var.service_name}-vpn"                    
  image_tag_mutability = "MUTABLE"            
  image_scanning_configuration {                              
    scan_on_push = true                                                  
  }                                               
  encryption_configuration {                               
    encryption_type = "AES256"                                           
  }                                                                      
}
```

In the .circleci/config.yml file I added these instructions:

```
docker_version: &docker_version
  version: 20.10.6 
orbs: 
  aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@8.2.1 
  aws-ecs: circleci/aws-ecs@3.2.0

jobs:
  build-and-deploy-image:
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker:
         <<: *docker_version
         docker_layer_caching: true

      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          aws-access-key-id: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          aws-secret-access-key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          aws-cli-version: latest
          extra-build-args: "--compress"
          region: AWS_REGION
          build-path: ./services/vpn/vpn-image/
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
          path: ./services/vpn/vpn-image/
          repo: vpn
          tag: "latest,${CIRCLE_SHA1}"
          registry-id: AWS_ECR_REGISTRY_ID

workflows:
  build_ecr_ecs_task:
    jobs:
      - build-and-deploy-image:
          requires:
            - apply-terraform-sandbox
      - aws-ecs/deploy-service-update:
          aws-access-key-id: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          aws-secret-access-key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          cluster: cluster-name
          container-image-name-updates: container=container-name,tag=latest
          family: service-name-vpn
            requires:
              - build-and-deploy-image
```